# data occupying space but cannot be found

Tags: hard-disk, fstab

when configuring an automount via fstab I made a mistake with defining the correct datasystem. Instead of ext4 I configured it to be ntfs. Whenever I copied files into the system I assume it copied it to my system drive instead to the configured hard drive. I noticed it when my hard drive was full, while I just started copying to my brand new high storage hard drive. So I freed up some space and reconfigured fstab. The new hard drive works now as expected.

The problem I now have is that the system still somehow assumes the files are still occupying space. So I use the Disk Usage Analyzer. Seeing the main view of the application it tells me my hard drive is used by 420gb. When doing the analysis with the tool, it only shows me that about 150gb are used. This correlates in size with the data on the other hard drive which I copied when fstab was configured wrong. Now I am unable to find the data occupying space on my hard drive, such that I can free the space up again.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmount the filesystem in question (this one you make mistake with the type) and check under the mountpoint. With high probability the files are there (under the mountpoint). And they use diskspace and you can't find them (kind of hidden)

Comment: Perfect, this worked like a charm!